# Percentage of homes bought in London for living in

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, first-time-home-buyer, london

I am investigating a possibility of buying a flat in London to live in. On Rightmove it is possible to see flats/homes that were recently sold, and often it looks like the price per number of square meters is very large for the given location (for example £500000 for 45 square meters in Kenitsh town). So I have a problem to believe that a person who buys such a home will actually live in it (I might be wrong). Hence the question:

Is there some available statistics concerning the percentage of homes (flats) bought in London with intention to live there subsequently?

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  Someone buys a flat, what do you think they are going to do with it other than live in it; or, rent it to have someone life there?  While that price might be high for a small place in some places, it is probably cheap in others.  London is a high priced housing city.  Why does this even enter into your decision?  There are plenty of fine people in London, where are you suggesting they live if your thesis is true?

Comment: Dear Pete, sorry for confusion. My only guess was that such a place would be bought to be rented out. I might be completely wrong...

Comment: But why do you think that flats to be rented sell for more than flats to be owner-occupied? I would expect that if there is a difference at all, it is in the opposite direction. Rentals come with some additional costs, so people might be slightly more willing to pay extra for a flat to live in themselves than for one to be rented out.

Comment: @TooTea, I was not thinking along the lines that you suggest. I just look at the price - 0.5 million and square meters - 45. And I try to imaging a person who will buy such a flat to live in it. And I fail, because 0.5 million looks big but 45 sq meters look small (this is very subjective of course) and the location is just standard one.

Comment: @aglearner Yeah, but following that logic, why would anyone want to rent that same flat for enough to pay for the purchase price, any additional associated costs, and a decent profit for the landlord as well? Housing prices in central London may well seem insane compared to other locations, but it's pretty much the same in the center of any major city. If you want to live downtown, you simply have to pay a lot.

Comment: @TooTea I hope I understood your question. I imaging the following scenario. I am a guy who owns several homes (a prosperous landlord). I have money to buy this flat and buy it  in order to rent, in a hope additionally that the price of the flat will go up. There will be people who would be happy to rent this flat (like real me) - because anyway they need to live somewhere in London, but they can't afford buying a house (like real me)

Comment: @aglearner Right, but said landlord still wants to turn a reasonable profit on said flat, so that means the monthly rent has to be significantly more than £2000 (excluding utilities). That also sounds like quite a lot, doesn't it? And people who can afford to spend that much on rent can typically also afford a half-a-million mortgage.

Comment: @TooTea Thanks! It is interesting. Could you explain me how you get the figure >£2000? Why would the said landlord need to ask so much? Indeed, if you rent such a flat for 25 years for £1700, you already get back the price of the house (+ the house itself). I agree £1700 sounds a lot, and maybe they will only be able to rent it out for £1400-£1500, judging by what Rightmove says about that location

Comment: @aglearner: It's not really what the landlord needs to ask, but what they CAN ask in a given market.  If a landlord can cover costs for £1700/month, but can get £2000/month or more in the current market, why on Earth would you not expect them to take the extra profit?

Comment: @jamesqf Because if I look around this place (Kentish town - Tuffnel park) for a flat that is 45 sq meters, it is not £2000  per month, rather £1500. So, to answer your question - I am very happy for them to take the extra profit, but no one will rent their flat for £2000... Why rent their flat for £2000 if you can get the same quality at the same place for £1500? My question to TooTea was the following: why £0.5 million equates to renting the flat out for £2000? Was £2000 just a random number, or there is some reason for choosing it?

Comment: @aglearner: But if they can't rent their flat for £2000 in the current market, then they need to lower the rent.  Really, this is just basic economics.  And I chose £2000 because a couple of comments just prior used that number.  I have no idea of current London housing prices, as I haven't been to Britain for a couple of decades.

Comment: @aglearner I just pulled that number out of thin air as a reasonable target rent. A very rough rule of thumb is that the purchase price should equal twenty years worth of rent. £2000 per month on a £500k investment is just 4.8% gross return per year, and that's before tax, maintenance and administration costs, for a relatively risky asset. It doesn't really make much sense to go much lower; you can get that kind of a return from a traditional bonds+stocks portfolio which requires much less effort to maintain.

Comment: @TooTea Thanks for explaining this number the reasoning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are statistics, although perhaps not exactly what you are looking for.

It's not possible to produce accurate data that says "Person X bought House Y for Price Z and intended to live in it as their primary house / have it as a secondary home for themselves or their family / rent it out / leave it standing empty" because you don't have to report the purpose of a house purchase when you buy the house.

However, the Mayor of London / London Assembly produces an annual report about housing in London which for example in the [most recent one](https://www.london.gov.uk/sites/default/files/housing_in_london_2020.pdf) says (in section 1.13 of the linked PDF) that somewhere around 40% of houses in London are owner-occupied.

Even if you did have information that the example property you found the sale price of was a buy-to-let vs primary residence vs second home, what would you do with that information? You can't say to the vendor "Hey, you might get more if you sell it to a buy-to-let landlord than if you sell it to me, but I intend to live in it myself!" - or more precisely, you can say that, but it is very unlikely to get you anywhere....

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for pointing out this figure 40%!  You are asking "what would you do with that information"? Well, if I learn that flats like this are mainly not primary homes, I would probably stop looking for a flat in such locations, and will look elsewhere.

Comment: I decided to accept the answer, since the document you attached is really informative and covers far more than what I could expect. (It looks like my question goes a bit against the standards of this site though...)